# Windows Autologin Issues

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

We have kiosk computers that have been configured to autologin for years with a non-privileged account. All the sudden yesterday, the autologin is no longer functioning on any of them, and it is failing in a very unique/interesting way that we don't quite understand. First, we have autologin configured in the registry by creating the below registry keys, but have also tried using SysInternals's Autologon application and the same issue occurs:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon (REG_SZ) set to "1"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName (REG_SZ) set to "mydomain"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultUserName (REG_SZ) set to "myusername"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultPassword (REG_SZ) set to "mypassword"
```

It successfully enters the account's credentials into the username/password box, then just... sits there at the login screen. It's like it doesn't just "press enter" to submit the credentials. If we come up to the kiosk and do nothing at all but touch the arrow next to the password box on the kiosk's touchscreen, the account signs in just fine, but it doesn't do so automatically anymore and we can't seem to figure out why. To the best of our knowledge, nothing has changed to cause this to happen in the last couple of days. No GPO changes, no updates, etc. Any guidance/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: These registry tweaks work fine here. Is Windows fully updated ?

Comment: Yes, Windows is fully up to date. Windows 10 22H2 with current patches.

Comment: Something has still changed. Maybe some installed product updated itself, for example an antivirus?

Comment: Possibly. We use Windows Defender for Endpoint, so basically just Microsoft's built-in AV with some enterprise logging/tracking capabilities.

Comment: Do you have perhaps enabled System Restore and can try to rollback one such computer to before this happened?

Comment: Pretty sure it is, and that's worth a shot. I'll take a look and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: The only restore point was from 10/29. Restoring to that did not resolve the issue, unfortunately. We are attempting a fresh install of Windows 11 to see if we can replicate the issue. If it works, we'll try swapping it into our kiosk cabinet and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: The fact that it happened simultaneously to all the computers : if the computers are in a domain or centrally controlled in some way, this might have changed.

Comment: We started experiencing a different (but I think related) issue on other computers that do not have automatic login enabled. At the login screen, the user is no longer being given the option to enter their username unless they click "sign-in options" and then click an option that has "local or domain account password" text when hovering over it. It's not defaulting to requiring username and password even though our GPOs are configured to require that via the "Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in" option.

Comment: Sorry, but that problem is local to your domain/company, and not a problem of Windows. IT support is off-subject on our site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because IT support is off-subject.

Comment: IT support MAY be off topic. If it is the IT person asking, that is usually allowed. However, OP, please note that I agree with harrymc that these changes do appear to be caused by/related to changes that happened within your domain, and are not something inherent to Windows. Your environment was changed by IT and is responding to that change. If you didn't make the change, someone else in IT did, and you need to find and communicate with them.

Comment: The notes on the MS Doc page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon) lists a couple reasons it can misbehave. I've seen this happen when a 2-factor app like Duo gets installed on kiosk machines (even when the user account is not registered/using the app)

Comment: Just wanted to update everyone in case others see a similar issue. The newest version of the Dell Encryption Management Agent caused this problem.